# How to use the same var on different events

Tags: c#, events, uwp-xaml

I want to use double test in the second event how can I do it?
I don't want to define double test again in the second event I want to use reference.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double test = double.Parse(txt.Text);
            test // I want to use this var in the event below how
        }

        public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            test // doesn't recognaize double test in the first event
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the keyword `var` in your code at all (except in a comment)?  The term `var` is a C# keyword - do you mean _variable_?  You can make `test` be either a _field_ or a _property_ of your `MainPage` class by using something like `private double _test = default;` or `private double Test {get; set;}`

Answer (score 2):

you can do this if you create a member variable like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    double test = 0;
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        test  = double.Parse(txt.Text);
        //test // I want to use this var in the event below how
    }

    public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
        //test // doesn't recognaize double test in the first event
    }
}
```

Comment: Conventionally we out class level members under `class`, or more rarely at the bottom, rather than mixing them into the middle of the method declarations. Prefixing them with an underscore also helps set them apart visually  from local variables